# How do I register a custom IObjectRenderer in log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm doing some research into using log4net, and I found the *IObjectRenderer* interface interesting.  It would allow us to control how types are logged and provide a different, possibly more user-friendly `ToString()` implementation.  I just started looking at log4net though, and can't seem to find a logical way to programmatically set up the association between types and renderers.

I found that this can be set up in the XML configuration file by reading the [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#HC-13011608), but it didn't give me any hints about programmatically adding these.  It seems to me that you'd rather have a programmatic object renderer in some cases, so I'm curious how to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I poked around with it some while writing the question and came up with this:

```
using System.IO;
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.ObjectRenderer;
using log4net.Util;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BasicConfigurator.Configure();

            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
            var repo = LogManager.GetRepository();
            repo.RendererMap.Put(typeof(Foo), new FooRenderer());

            var fooInstance = new Foo() { Name = "Test Foo" };
            log.Info(fooInstance);
        }
    }

    internal class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    internal class FooRenderer : log4net.ObjectRenderer.IObjectRenderer
    {
        public void RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, object obj, TextWriter writer)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                writer.Write(SystemInfo.NullText);
            }

            var fooInstance = obj as Foo;
            if (fooInstance != null)
            {
                writer.Write("", fooInstance.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(SystemInfo.NullText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not certain if this is the correct way to do this, but I do know that it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add this line to the root of your log4net if you don't want to register your renderer programatically

```
<renderer renderingClass="ConsoleApplication1.FooRenderer" renderedClass="ConsoleApplication1.Foo" />
```