# How do I configure log4net such that properties of an object can be mapped to the log output?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am attempting to provide a means to log errors that occur in our Flex client by providing a SOAP web service which takes as a single parameter a LogMessage object.

```
public class LogMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

This object is populated by the Flex client should a client side error surface and the LogClientError method is invoked which logs the error via log4net.

```
[WebMethod()]
public void LogClientError(LogMessage message) 
{
    rollingLogger.Error(message);
}
```

Currently this prints the fully qualified name of the LogMessage class, so my current assumption is that log4net simply calls .ToString() on the object that is passed in.

However, what I really want to be able to do is map each property in the LogMessage class to a pattern so that log4net will correctly write out the desired information. I would like to do this in such a manner that the typical appenders (DB, File, SMTP) are all still supported.

How do I configure log4net such that properties of an object can be mapped to the log output?

Answer (score 3):

log4net has two paths you can take. The first would be to create a custom object renderer for LogMessage instances. You need to implement [the IObjectRenderer interface](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.ObjectRenderer.IObjectRenderer.html) and [register the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175109/how-do-i-register-a-custom-iobjectrenderer-in-log4net).

The other route, which would be more reusable, is to subclass the patternlayout class. Your custom pattern layout could then support a special syntax for naming properties which the layout could use to reflect on the incoming message object.

Answer (score 0):

If LogMessage is partial you could create a ToString() method on LogMessage.