# log4net - Custom property logging

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I got use the following class to print out messages using log4net:

```
public class Message
{
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

I use `Logger.Info(MessageInstance)`, so log4net just invokes the `ToString` method and prints out the message. I would like to also log the `Id` property of the message object, but I cannot figure out how to achive this.

My conversion pattern looks similiar to this:

```
<conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %message%newline" />
```

I tried adding `%message{Id}` but that would just print the whole message twice.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Does it need to be in a particular format? If not then you could just amend your ToString() method to include the Id.

Comment: I need to be free when it comes to the position of the proprety whithin the output. So putting it into the ToString method is not just bad design, but also would't solve my issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I configure log4net such that properties of an object can be mapped to the log output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041751/how-do-i-configure-log4net-such-that-properties-of-an-object-can-be-mapped-to-th)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote a custom pattern, which allows to read properies of the message object.

```
public class ReflectionReader : PatternLayoutConverter
{
    public ReflectionReader()
    {
        _getValue = GetValueFirstTime;
    }

    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        writer.Write(_getValue(loggingEvent.MessageObject));
    }

    private Func<object, String> _getValue;
    private string GetValueFirstTime(object source)
    {
        _targetProperty = source.GetType().GetProperty(Option);
        if (_targetProperty == null)
        {
            _getValue = x => "<NULL>";
        }
        else
        {
            _getValue = x => String.Format("{0}", _targetProperty.GetValue(x, null));
        }
        return _getValue(source);
    }

    private PropertyInfo _targetProperty;
}
```

Combine with this:

```
public class ReflectionLayoutPattern : PatternLayout
{
    public ReflectionLayoutPattern()
    {
        this.AddConverter("item", typeof(ReflectionReader));
    }
}
```

Config looks like this:

```
<layout type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.ReflectionLayoutPattern, MyAssembly">
  <conversionPattern value="[%item{Id}]&#9;%message%newline" />
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CustomXmlLayout class that derives from [XmlLayoutBase](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutBase.html) and override the FormatXml method. This method takes a LoggingEvent object as parameter which will contain the MessageObject that was passed to the log method.

```
public class SpecialXmlLayout : XmlLayoutBase
{
    protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        Message message = loggingEvent.MessageObject as Message;
        writer.WriteStartElement("LoggingEvent");
        writer.WriteElementString("Message", GetMessage(message));
        // ... write other things
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Inside the GetMessaage method create your string as you would like from the message.

Then use this layout class in log4net config:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <applicationName value="My Application" />
      <layout type="Namespace.SpecialXmlLayout">
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

This is the idea. For more specific details you will have to consult the log4Net SDK documentation.