# formatting a custom property in log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, type-conversion

I have the following conversionPattern for a log4net appender. I am setting a custom property in code (a DateTime object), and i'm able to output the property to a log4net log.

```
<appender name="FilteredLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${USERPROFILE}\logs\UserConfiguredFilteredLog.txt" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="[Header]&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <!-- I don't think I can apply custom formating on the CustomDate property-->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %property{LoggerCategory} [UserCustomTime:%property{CustomDate}] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

My question is: How can I format the CustomDate property that I set? I've tried adding %d and -d and stuff like that in various combination, but can't figure it out. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806793/log4net-custom-property-logging) SO question describes a solution

Comment: The easiest way would be to format the value before you send it to log4net, ie when you set the property value

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are putting the custom property on the log4net.ThreadLogicalContext which is of type DateTime . Why not put it in string format instead of the DateTime type. This make the output a lot easier as trying to add a layout into your configuration.

Comment: yes, I am assigning it like: loggingEvent.Properties["MyPropName"] = myDate (I dont have the exact code on me). I realize I could store it as a string and format it to my choosing, but I was hoping to give the user to configure this at the app.config level if possible.

Comment: It seems already very product specific. Is it to fix you issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006757/using-a-logger-date-other-than-the-local-system-time

Comment: Yes, it is for that question. Perhaps I should have posted my findings there about the custom property, but I didn't have a complete answer yet.